# Why pyglet couldn't draw octagon?

Tags: python, pyglet

I was trying to create an 2D octagon here, and for some reason, I didn't succeded. the output is just a black screen. I am pretty sure the problem is inside this part of code:

```
def on_draw(self):

    self.clear()
    glBegin(GL_OCTAGONS)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(0,0)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(10,0)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(15,5)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(15,15)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(10,20)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(0,20)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(-5,15)
    glColor3ub(0,255,0)
    glVertex2f(-5,5)
    glEnd()
```

Comment: I can find no reference to there being any such thing as `GL_OCTAGONS` defined in pyglet; there are exactly ten valid parameters to `glBegin()`, `GL_POLYGON` appears to be the closest to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yepp [GL_POLYGON](https://taskercode.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/gl-primitives-with-background.png) is probably the one you need. Have a search for `GL Primitives` and you'll see a valid assortment of primitives that you can use, OCTAGON is not a shape/primitive that's defined in the GL space since polygon solves that and many more shape options : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GL_OCTAGONS` is not a valid argument to [`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml). This is just an arbitrary assumption from you. You've to use one of the OpenGL [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive) types.
Use either `GL_POLYGON` or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`:

<s>`glBegin(GL_OCTAGONS)`</s>

```py
glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
```